# Scrapy engine_stopped signal fired before all items are through pipelines?

Tags: python, scrapy, signals, twisted, pipeline

I am a relative noob regarding Scrapy. I am trying to implement a feature that tracks how long it takes for a Scrapy spider from the crawl command until all insets/updates are done.

I've written an [extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html) that uses the `engine_started` and `engine_stopped` [signals](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html). This is working fine except for the fact that the `engine_stopped` signal is fired half way during the inserts/updates in the pipelines.

So my question is: Is there any way to check that all pipelines are empty and scrapy is completely finished with crawling and inserting/updating?

Note: I am using `twisted.enterprise.adbapi` in my pipeline, my gut feeling is that that might be the reason why the `engine_stopped` signal is fired early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the execution time inside the [`item_scraped` signal](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#item-scraped):

> Sent when an item has been scraped, after it has passed all the Item Pipeline stages (without being dropped).

This way, when the last item would pass the "pipeline" stage - you'll catch it and measure your total execution time.

<sup>(this is not tested)</sup>

Comment: Inerteresting approach, but how would you know what the last item is. It would be possible to overwrite some value when a item scraped is fired, but then the script will never really end right?

Comment: @Supahsmooth thanks, I meant just recalculate the execution time every time you are inside the `item_scraped` signal handler. But, yes, you would not know how much items left..I can be wrong, this is something you need to try out..

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be to implement your own [Feed Exporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html)

The [finish_exporting](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/19a4a0adf953d2a3d428411b6b0306997276238c/scrapy/exporters.py#L105) method should give you a decent idea of end-time.

Comment: why would someone downvote this? It's a suggestion. Tell me what I did wrong.